# Visual Basic if active cell contains text "a" then insert a 1 into the cell to the right

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

The task is if the currently selected cell contains an "a" then insert a 1 in the cell to the right and (because of data below) insert a new row below and fill the cell below the 1 with a 0.

So if the cell contains an "a" then when the macro runs it leaves;
a 1
  0

With the 1 being in the cell to the right of the a and the 1 being in a new row, in the cell directly below the 1.

The code I currently have is;

```
Sub ChangeAToCells()
Dim text As String
text = "a"
Dim text0 As String
text = "b"
Dim text1 As String
text = "0"
Dim text2 As String
text = "1"


If ActiveCell = text Then
ActiveCell.Formula = text1
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = text2
End If



End Sub
```

The problems are clear, the selection of cells isn't working and I can't get the loop exit right,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub ChangeAToCells()
If ActiveCell = "a" Then
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = 1
   ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1) = 0
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect that code to do? You first assign 4 different values to the same string, then compare a cell with a string, and if they're the same, you set the value of two cells to the values of two strings you haven't initialized.

I think you meant to initialize `text0`, `text1` and `text2` as well, instead of initializing `text` four times.

I don't understand what you mean by 'edit loop'. There is no loop in your code.

Comment: OK I missed the initialize mistake, but the code is indeed rubbish, and I don't mean loop, if statement instead. Mistkes aside, I'm sure this can be done a different way completely to be correct and efficient. I need the code to fill the cell to the right with a 1, if the current cell contains an a and then insert a row with the cell below the cell now filled with 1 with a 0.

Comment: Apart from these errors, the code works. Well, it does *something*. ActiveCell can indeed be compared with "a". It will be True if ActiveCell contains the letter "a" (and nothing else!). Then, the current cell (a) is overwritten with the value of Text1 variable, an empty line is inserted, the cell below the current cell is selected, and Text2 is inserted. So, it seems to work, except you forgot to jump to the right: `ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Select`